# How to include an "OR" statement in SQL for "no value"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL script that tells me if any of my employees have any open service orders that have not been updated in the past 48 hours. It looks like this (simplified) -

```
select ServiceOrder, RepName from NotesTable

join OrdersTable on OrdersTable.OrderNumber=NotesTable.OrderNumber

having (DATEDIFF(day,max(NotesTable.LastModified),GETDATE()) >2)
```

Which basically just takes todays date, subtracts the last modified date of most recent note, and spits out the numbers of service orders that haven't been modified in 48 hours.

My problem is, if a service order has *no* notes, this script doesn't work. So even though it hasn't been updated in 48 hours it doesn't come out on the report. What kind of "or" do I need to say "also tell me if it has no notes."

I thought about joining another table that contains a "dateopened" field and then,

```
OR (DATEDIFF(day,(NotesTable.DateOpened),GETDATE()) >2)
```

but that returns every service order older than 48 hours, so that doesn't help.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you post more information about your model? What do you mean by "if a service order has no notes"?

Comment: You need to provide more information. The query you provided is obviously incomplete and without seeing more of it, this question is too difficult (or maybe impossible) to answer.

Comment: Your query can't be compiled, therefor i can't understand what you want.

Comment: You're querying against the wrong table. If you want to get all ServiceOrders, regardless of the presence/absence of a related record in your notes table, you need to query against the service orders table, not the notes table. Join the service orders table to your notes table.

Comment: You should post your table structure and some sample data.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated/clarified above. I tried to simply the querry to make it easier to read and apparently I made it harder ;)

Comment: What if a value on OrdersTable was updated more recently than the latest note?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you are still missing parts of your query (the `GROUP BY`, for example), but this should give you an idea of what you want:

```
SELECT ServiceOrder, RepName 
FROM OrdersTable 
LEFT JOIN NotesTable
    ON OrdersTable.OrderNumber = NotesTable.OrderNumber
GROUP BY ServiceOrder, RepName 
HAVING (DATEDIFF(DAY,MAX(NotesTable.LastModified),GETDATE()) >2)
OR MAX(NotesTable.LastModified) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

If every record in your [Orders] table has a [NotesTable] record by default then this would work.

Change [NotesTable].[LastModified] to Isnull([NotesTable].[LastModified],[NotesTable].[DateOpened])... 
This will use the "LastModified" if it exists and if it does not will use the "DateOpened" instead.

Comment: And what happens if when op says that *an order has no notes*, then it means that there are no rows on the table `NotesTable`?

Comment: @Lamak I'm assuming that all records that exist in [NotesTable] should have a "LastModified" value as activity occurs on it and that a Null value for this column should only persist until the time some activity occurs in which case I figure Zac would want it on this report. I think the scenario you're concerned with would be if you left joined some other table to NotesTable, but in this case the "DateOpened" would still be Null so it wouldn't meet the Having criteria.

Comment: But you are assuming that every order has a record on the table `NotesTable`, even if it has no notes?, that's a pretty big assumption (that's why people was asking for clarification).

Comment: @Lamak The [NotesTable] has a column called [DateOpened] and he said when he changes the logic to the [DateOpened] that it includes everything older than two days. I don't think that is that big of a stretch. I understand your point, but I don't think my inference was too far fetched.

Comment: Ok, maybe your inference isn't that far fetched. But I'd rather have verification from op that this is the right way

Comment: @Lamak - You are correct, if an order has no notes, it means there are no rows in the table. The "DateOpened" is in a different table I have joined to this one.

Comment: I have updated the original question to make it clear that the second thought requires joining another table.

Comment: @Lamak Looks like you were right. That said Zac, your post is incorrect then because you aliased DateOpened as being from the NotesTable. You'd have to provide your full query to get specifics, but you're probably going to just want to move the having criteria to the join criteria using the same isnull logic. This could have potentional "Group By" implications depending on your query.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with "isnull" so I will go look that up and see how it can help. So I'm gathering there is no easy way to say, "if there is no record in the notes table for a given ServiceOrder number, output it on the list"?

Comment: You can do a "Not Exists" and union that to your original query, but there are more efficient ways to do it with a left join if you want both. If you want a copy paste answer I'd just provide the whole query and let someone give you the exact answer. If you're not familiar with IsNull there are definitely more knowledgeable people that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the other table that notes are related to. Maybe this is an orders table? Hopefully, that table has some field to indicate when it was last modified.

```
    select ServiceOrder, RepName from Orders
    left outer join NotesTable
    on Orders.OrderID = NotesTable.OrderID


    having (DATEDIFF(day,max(Coalesce(NotesTable.LastModified,
       Orders.LastModified)),GETDATE()) >2)
```

You may have to do a case statement instead of Coalesce to see which of the LastModified dates is more recent.

Answer (score -1):

You could use ISNULL (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

```
select ServiceOrder, RepName 
from NotesTable
having (DATEDIFF(day,max(ISNULL(NotesTable.LastModified,NotesTable.DateOpened )),GETDATE()) >2)
```